# How to setup the Facebook SDK for meteor js website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, sdk

I want to add Facebook features (create page, share post, upload images) to my website made in meteorjs . I am using facebook SDK but it doesn't works for me. Is there another alternative to do this ?

**Client Side Js**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxx',
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
};
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed'
});
```

Comment: Now, I am using Facebook Login for WEB with Javascript SDK.

Comment: Here is the link of full code -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the full description of Facebook Javascript SDK code ->

[Facebook_JS_SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the following packages `meteor add accounts-facebook service-configuration`.

In the server, initialize the service

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
```

And then create a button in your login template, and trigger this event.

```
Template.Login.events({
   'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
            }
        });
    },
});
```